# how to install JTDX package I downloaded

Tags: package-management, software-installation, 20.04

OK folks...I do know a little Linux; I install Ubuntu 20.04 on the recommentation of a friend. Appears to work fine. I went to JTDX web site and downloaded the program specific for Ubuntu 20.04. I can extract the .tar files...at that point I am lost. I am tired of looking on the web for instructions...

thanks, Gene

Comment: What it JTDX? From where you have downloaded it?

Comment: JTDX (and WSJT-X) are weak signal communications software run on Windows, Mac, and Linux--they have a download for Ubuntu 20.04...You would use it on ham radio bands...very popular. web site jtdx.tech...FILE: JTDX v2.1.0-rc150
(Ubuntu 20.04 64bit)....download: jtdx-2.1.0_rc150_2004_amd64.deb.....is the "amd" mean amd chip in lieu of Intel???

Answer (score 0):

The *amd64* in the name is traditional naming for 64-bit (AMD64) CPU architecture. Now it is universal for both Intel and AMD.

About the installation - it is straightforward - download deb-file and install by double clicking on it.

For example from terminal with assumption that deb-file was saved in ~/Downloads folder:

```
cd ~/Downloads
sudo apt-get install ./jtdx-2.1.0-rc150_2004_amd64.deb
```

Then you have to install one additional dependency to allow application to launch with

```
sudo apt-get install libgfortran5
```

And then you can launch JTDX and use it.

Comment: did that; but cannot remember how to launch....it has been a while since I worked wiwth linux...sorry

Comment: the terminal output is too long to fit in the comment box...Gene